# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str error

Tags: python

I'm making a python that changes lines through arguments, but it's giving an error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Script:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

pathh = os.path.basename(__file__)
pathhh = pathh.replace("py", "exe")
path_to_file = f'{sys.argv[1]}'
path = Path(path_to_file)

if path.is_file():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
            lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
            lines[line_num] = text
            out = open(file_name, 'w')
            out.writelines(lines)
            out.close()
    
    my_list = [f'{sys.argv[1]}', f'{sys.argv[2]}', f'{sys.argv[3]}']
    my_str = '0'
    my_str2 = '1'
    my_str3 = '2'
    result = my_list[int(my_str)]
    result1 = my_list[int(my_str2)]
    result2 = my_list[int(my_str3)]
    replace_line(f'{result}', f'{result1}', f'{result2}')
else:
    print(f"Usage: {pathh} <File> <LINE> <TOEDIT>")
    print("This program was made by CookieYT#9267")
else:
    print(f"Usage: {pathh} <File> <LINE> <TOEDIT>")
    print("This program was made by CookieYT#9267")
```

I've tried several ways, and nothing

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You can't have more than one `else:` block for an `if`.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line_num` argument to `replace_line()` is supposed to be an integer, so you can use it in `lines[line_num]`. So don't format it as a string when you call the function.

There's no need to put the other arguments in f-strings, either, since they're already strings.

```
replace_line(result, result1, result2)
```

Similarly, all the elements of `sys.argv` are strings, you don't need to put them in f-strings, either. So you should write

```
my_list = sys.argv[1:4]
```

And if you just want to convert a variable to a string, use `str(variable)` rather than `f'{variable}'`. They're equivalent, but `str()` is the more common idiom. F-strings should be used when you need to add more formatting text, combine multiple variables, or need to specify formatting options (e.g. field size, justification, number of decimal places, etc.).